# Show total size of multiple files in HP UX

Tags: hp-ux

Please tell me which command in HP-UX is used to show total size of multiple files? I want to know the HP-UX command similar to this linux command:
du -bc test*.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check df (works to a fashion) or bdf.

Answer (score 0):

```
du -sk <list of file names> | awk '{ sum+=$1 } END { print sum }'
```

Example 1:

```
$ du -sk savecron12282015 gisp_rman_purge.txt gisp_rman_purge.out1| awk '{ sum+=$1 } END { print sum }'

344
```

Example 2:

```
$ du -sk sql* | awk '{ sum+=$1 } END { print sum }'

48
```